# Parent-child relation, without using PHP fetching and re-using the returning value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a relation between two tables. I can do what I want with fetching the data with PHP and using returning value again in a query. But as far as I researched, it doesn't seem an efficient method.

How can I get the winning coupons when I'm finalizing the bet #3 as YES with a SQL query?

(It should return 3 and 4)

Coupon table,

```
ID coupon_id bets bets_played  played_by
0    2        2       yes         JOHN
1    2        3       no          JOHN
2    3        1       yes         JANE
3    3        3       yes         JANE
4    4        3       yes         SARAH
5    4        2       no          SARAH
```

Bets table,

```
ID  result
1    yes
2    no
3    NULL
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to show those bets which bets_played :yes and bets :3 ?

Comment: I want to show all coupons that fully contains only WON bets. (in this example, when bet #3 finalize, two coupon 2 and 3 is the result of what I say)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct c.*
from coupon c
join bets b on b.result = c.bets_played and b.result = 'yes'
```

Comment: Thanks Naveed, but this is only returning coupon ID #3 and not both 2 and 3

Comment: I have updated the query with respect to BET YES please try this.

Comment: This returned all coupons in a weird way :/
http://i.hizliresim.com/W1YoG4.png

Comment: select distinct c.* from coupon c join bets b on b.result = c.bets_played and b.result = 'yes' Try this.

Comment: I changed the SQL a bit, and it gave me what I want. Thank you.